# Hyperledger: Cannot find module grpc_node.node error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I keep facing this error when i tried to run enrollAdmin.js in hyperledger

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:32:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

I am able to find the file in my file directory but for some reason the module is unable to be found when I run the code.

I have ran npm install multiple times, as well as npm install grpc, but this doesn't not seem to solve the problem. Kindly advise

---

I ran the first npm install on the file and this is the msg

```
Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary>npm install
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer

> grpc@1.15.1 install Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[grpc] Success: "Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN The package lodash is included as both a dev and production dependency.

added 225 packages from 555 contributors and audited 655 packages in 62.783s
found 16 vulnerabilities (1 low, 14 moderate, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I also ran a rebuild afterwards

The file grpc_node.node is created but no luck with the same error finding the module.

---

**Update**
I realise the extension reference is different

```
Downloads\Hyperledger\fabric-samples-release-1.2\fabcar\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown
```

Hence reran the npm install and met with this error instead

node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.10.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.10.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. Create directory : `<FABCAR_DIR>/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/`
2. Run `npm install` in
3. Run `npm rebuild` in

step 2 or 3 - one of them should solve the problem - try in the same order.

You can see if node_modules installed successfully:

*[grpc] Success: "/home/ms/fabric-samples-release-1.2/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote*

After step 2 OR step 3 - you should see a file.

`<FABCAR_DIR>/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v46-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node`

After that enroll admin should succeed like:

*sprint @ fabcar>node enrollAdmin.js Store path:/home/ms/fabric-samples-release-1.2/fabcar/hfc-key-store Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" Assigned the admin user to the fabric client ::{"name":"admin","mspid":"Org1MSP","roles":null,"affiliation":"","enrollmentSecret":"","enrollment":{"signingIdentity":"42d8536072cf7e47358c137b254d78d8e853934caee70d03dbec06a22f482ad9","identity":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----}*

if u look closely, the output of startFabric.sh prints

" Start by installing required packages run `npm install` Then run `node enrollAdmin.js`, then `node registerUser.js` "

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no pre-built binary for Node 10. Can you switch to Node8 or a different Node 10 version and try again?

`ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.10.0`